# Unable to change registry entry through Inno Setup Installer

Tags: registry, inno-setup

I want to write installer for the application which is designed for x64 Windows 10. I have defined in Inno Setup Script:

```
[Setup]
MinVersion=10.0.14393
ArchitecturesAllowed=x64
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64
AlwaysRestart=yes
```

Also I want that during the installation, long paths will be enabled in Windows registry. I added following code:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM64; Subkey: "System\CurrentcontrolSet\Control\FileSystem"; ValueType: dword; ValueName: "LongPathsEnabled"; ValueData: "1"; Flags: createvalueifdoesntexist; Permissions: users-modify
Root: HKLM64; Subkey: "System\ControlSet001\Control\FileSystem"; ValueType: dword; ValueName: "LongPathsEnabled"; ValueData: "1"; Flags: createvalueifdoesntexist; Permissions: users-modify
```

When I run the installer on my personal computer and restart, registry entries are changed, but when my colleague runs the installer and restarts, entries are not changed. The application itself works on both our computers. We both have x64 Windows 10 systems and administrator rights. What might be the reasons this script is failing on some computers?

The log file content for the computer, where entries **are not** changed:

```
2019-10-09 09:44:41.296   Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem
2019-10-09 09:44:41.296   Value name: LongPathsEnabled
2019-10-09 09:44:41.296   Setting permissions on key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem
2019-10-09 09:44:41.296   Starting 64-bit helper process.
2019-10-09 09:44:41.328   Helper process PID: 3248
2019-10-09 09:44:41.343   Creating or opening the key.
2019-10-09 09:44:41.343   Successfully created the key.
2019-10-09 09:44:41.343   -- Registry entry --
2019-10-09 09:44:41.343   Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\ControlSet001\Control\FileSystem
2019-10-09 09:44:41.343   Value name: LongPathsEnabled
2019-10-09 09:44:41.343   Setting permissions on key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\ControlSet001\Control\FileSystem
2019-10-09 09:44:41.343   Creating or opening the key.
2019-10-09 09:44:41.343   Successfully created the key.
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the [`createvalueifdoesntexist` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection&anchor=createvalueifdoesntexist).

That's what causes the problem and you do not want it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

What finally seems to be working is checking if the value is already in the register, and if not setting the value with flag `createvalueifdoesntexist`. Otherwise, the value is jus changed.

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM64; Subkey: "System\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem"; ValueType: dword; ValueName: "LongPathsEnabled"; ValueData: "1"; Permissions: users-modify; Flags: createvalueifdoesntexist; Check: LPECurrentControlSetNotInRegistry
Root: HKLM64; Subkey: "System\ControlSet001\Control\FileSystem"; ValueType: dword; ValueName: "LongPathsEnabled"; ValueData: "1"; Permissions: users-modify; Flags: createvalueifdoesntexist; Check: LPEControlSet001NotInRegistry
Root: HKLM64; Subkey: "System\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem"; ValueType: dword; ValueName: "LongPathsEnabled"; ValueData: "1"; Permissions: users-modify; Check: LPECurrentControlSetNotInRegistry
Root: HKLM64; Subkey: "System\ControlSet001\Control\FileSystem"; ValueType: dword; ValueName: "LongPathsEnabled"; ValueData: "1"; Permissions: users-modify; Check: LPEControlSet001NotInRegistry

[Code]
function LPECurrentControlSetNotInRegistry: Boolean;
begin
  if not RegValueExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'System\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem', 'LongPathsEnabled') then
  begin
    Result := True;
    Exit;
  end;
  Result := False;
end;

function LPEControlSet001NotInRegistry: Boolean;
begin
  if not RegValueExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'System\ControlSet001\Control\FileSystem', 'LongPathsEnabled') then
  begin
    Result := True;
    Exit;
  end;
  Result := False;
end;
```

Comment: Wouldn't `Root: HKLM64; Subkey: "System\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem"; ValueType: dword; ValueName: "LongPathsEnabled"; ValueData: "1"; Permissions: users-modify` achieve the same with a single line?

Comment: Thank you so much! That indeed is as simple as that, and does exactly what I want. The flag "createvalueifdoesntexist" got me completely confused, I was not aware that when used, it does not change value if key was already present in the registry. Nor was I aware that when this flag is not used and registry entry does not exist, it will be created.